# Lowering horizontal line relative to some text

Tags: line

Here's what I currently have :

[image]

Code is :

```
\begin{center}
\makebox[0.7\linewidth]{\Large{Name :} \hrulefill \ }\makebox[0.25\linewidth]{\Large{Class :} \hrulefill}
\end{center}
```

What I'm trying to get it to look like :

[image]

Basically, I need a way of lowering the horizontal lines relative to the text. Thank you.

Comment: Are you going to have text right below this line or is that text also supposed to get lowered?

Comment: I'm just trying to get the line lowered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\rule[<raise>]{<width>}{<height>}` to put a rule of width `<width>` and height `<height>`. `<raise>` - the optional argument - can be used to move the rule up or down (negative `<raise>`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Name: \rule{15em}{.4pt}\ Class: \rule{5em}{.4pt}

Name: \rule[-.2\baselineskip]{15em}{.4pt}\ Class: \rule[-.2\baselineskip]{5em}{.4pt}

\end{document}
```

Perhaps, if you wish to have the rule fill the entire line, you can use a number of `\hrulefill`s and actually raise the `Name:` and `Class:`:

```
\bigskip

\raisebox{.2\baselineskip}{Name:} \hrulefill\hrulefill\hrulefill\ 
\raisebox{.2\baselineskip}{Class:} \hrulefill
```

Answer (score 1):

One out of many many possible ways to do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\makebox[0.7\linewidth]{\Large{Name :} \hrulefill \ }\makebox[0.25\linewidth]{\Large{Class :} \hrulefill}
\end{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXlp{0.1\linewidth}}
~{\Large Name :} & & {\Large Class :} & \\[0.1cm] %<- adjust this vertical distance to fit your needs
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]